# Continuity of homegeneous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $F: R^2_+ \to R$ be positively homogeneous and monotonically increasing.  Is $F$ necessarily continuous?  Here, positively homogeneous means that $F(tx,ty) = tF(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in R^2_+$ and $t > 0$.  Monotonically increasing means that if $x_1 \ge x_2$ and $y_1 \ge y_2$, then $F(x_1,y_1) \ge F(x_2, y_2)$, ie, $F$ is increasing in $R^2_+$ when $R^2_+$ has the natural ordering.

Comment: What does increasing mean in this context?

Comment: I still have the same question. You would do well to define "positively homogeneous" and "increasing" in this context.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a sketch of an approach I think should work. Throughout this post I have written $F(x,y)$ as $f(x+yi)$. I am arguing that $f$ is continuous.

Say you have a sequence of complex numbers $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ that limit to $B\in R^{2}_+$ and you can pick out a subsequence such that $b_n<b_{n+1}$ in the sense that $\operatorname{Re}(b_n) \le \operatorname{Re}(b_{n+1})$ and $\operatorname{Im}(b_n)\le \operatorname{Im} 
(b_{n+1})$

> Our goal is to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}{f(b_n)}=f(B)$. This is the definition of $f$ continuous at $B$.

The plan here is to pick out a subsequence of $(b_n)$ such that each point is in between the two lines $L$ and $M$ where line $L$ contains the origin and $e^{i \theta}$ and $M$ is a line that contains the origin and $e^{i(\theta+\epsilon)}$.

Then define $L^x_n$ to be the point on $L$ with the same real part as $b_n$ and $(L^y_n)$ to be the point on $L$ with the same imaginary part as $b_n$. We define $L^x$ to the point on $L$ with same real part as $B$ and $L^y$ as the point on $L$ with the same imaginary part as as $B$.

We define $M^x_n, M_n^y, M^x, M^y$ analogously.

> Surely we have 
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(L^x_n)= f(L^x), \lim_{n\to\infty} f(L^y_n)= f(L^y), \lim_{n\to\infty} f(M^x_n)= f(M^x), \lim_{n\to\infty} f(M^y_n)= f(M^y) $$
>   We get all these limits because along $L$ and $M$ we have that $f$ is continuous along any line through the origin. We know that $f$ is continuous for any fixed $\theta$ because $f(r e^{i \theta})=rf(e^{i \theta})$. So here we have used the **homogeneity** of $f$.

But now what bounds do we have on $B$? And $b_n$?

> For this we use the **monotonicity** of $f$
>   $$f(M^x)<f(B)<f(L^x) \mbox{ and } f(L^y)<f(B)<f(M^y)$$
>   $$f(L^x_n)<f(b_n)<f(M_n^x) \mbox{ and } f(M_n^y)<f(B)<f(L_n^y)$$

And now I think good things happens as we take $\epsilon$ small. We can squeeze $b_n$s towards $f(B)$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  It's very helpful.  However, there seems to be one step missing that I can't fill.  As we take $\epsilon$ to be increasingly small, we hope that $f(L^x) \to f(M^x)$.  If this holds, we are done, because $f(B)$ lies between these two values.  But all we know is that $f$ is monotone, which means that there might be a jump discontinuity at precisely $B$, so that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} f(L^x) < f(B) \leq \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} f(M^x)$ (for instance).  Am I missing something? It seems that if $f$ is continuous along rays and along vertical and horizontal lines, $f$ is continuous.